# Jquery ajax() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function getActivityHP() which I am calling as soon as my page loads. This function makes an ajax calls to another test3.php page with certain data which will contain default values initially. However as soon as I add my ajax code the function stops working as if there is an error. Simple alert also doesn't work!

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready( function(){
   alert("Welcome");// not working
   getActivityHP();
   }

 function getActivityHP() {
    $("#loading").show();
    alert("Hello"); // not working 
    var search = $("#search").val();
    var deployedon = $("#deployedon").val();
    var platform = $("#platform").val();
    var country = $("#country").val();
    var carrier = $("#carrier").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test3.php",
      data: {
        "action"                    :   "activity",
        "deployedon"                :   deployedon,
        "platform"                  :   platform,
        "country"                   :   country,
        "carrier"                   :   carrier
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#activity").html(msg);

    }
    error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while processing file.");
  }
  });

  } 
 </script>
 In my test3.php I am doing:-

 $action=$_POST['action'];
 $deployedon=$_POST['deployedon'];
 $platform=$_POST['platform'];
 $carrier=$_POST['carrier'];
 $country=$_POST['country'];


 and then I am using echo to print these in my html!
```

Comment: are you getting the data from post method in test3.php ??

Comment: no I am not geting the data there!

Comment: Have you checked my answer and updated your code ? Is ajax request working. pls check in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error. You are missing `)` at the end of -

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   alert("Welcome");
   getActivityHP();
});
```

And missing `,` at the end of success -

```
success: function(msg) {
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#activity").html(msg);
},
```

Update your code and try to run.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma right here:

```
success: function(msg) {
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#activity").html(msg);

}, // <--- This comma
error: function() {
alert("An error occurred while processing file.");
```

Comment: Thank you!made the change but unfortunately still not working.